# Decreasing space before and after figure in latex

Tags: latex, texmaker

How can I decrease the marked spacing after figure in latex ? I am using TexMaker to write.

[image]

Comment: Please show the LaTeX code that produces this figure.

Answer (score -2):

I think the figure you are importing to LaTeX might have blank margin. If it does have blank margin try to

- crop your figure using your desired tool(e.g. acrobat reader).
- then import the figure to LaTeX.